# Merging with conditions in R

Tags: r, merge, conditional-statements

```
varA=c('2018-01-03', '2018-01-25','2018-01-15','2018-01-06')
varB=c('2018-01-02', '2018-01-05', '2018-01-13', '2018-01-21', '2018-01-26')
varC=c(201801,201802,201804,201809,201815)

df1=as.data.frame(varA)
df2=as.data.frame(cbind(varB,varC))
```

Using the code above to get the dataframes:

```
        varA
1 2018-01-03
2 2018-01-25
3 2018-01-15
4 2018-01-06
```

and

```
        varB   varC
1 2018-01-02 201801
2 2018-01-05 201802
3 2018-01-13 201804
4 2018-01-21 201809
5 2018-01-26 201815
```

From this I want to merge df1 and df2 together, but on a condition where if varA as a date is between two dates of varB it will take the varC from the earliest date. I think it's easier to show what I'd expect as a result:

```
       varA    varB         varC
1 2018-01-03  2018-01-02   201801
2 2018-01-25  2018-01-21   201809
3 2018-01-15  2018-01-13   201804
4 2018-01-06  2018-01-05   201802
```

Hopefully that's clear. I'm not sure how to get the output desired.

Comment: Any attempt from your part ? did you try something ?

Comment: I don't know where to start, I'm used to straight forward merges. That's why I thought to post on here.

Comment: first step would be to make a fonction, which associate a  `varA` value, the correct `varB` value (earliest etc...). Then you can use `for`/`apply` to use  this fonction for each row of DF1. Then you can use `merge`.

Comment: @timat I don't really know how to do this so an example would be great if you could create one? The question only has a small subset of my data as my actual data has 5000 rows. These rows have over 100 different dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a left join using `data.table`:

```
varA <- c('2018-01-03', '2018-01-25','2018-01-15','2018-01-06')
varB <- c('2018-01-02', '2018-01-05', '2018-01-13', '2018-01-21', '2018-01-26')
varC <- c(201801,201802,201804,201809,201815)

library(lubridate)
dt1 <- data.table(varA = ymd(varA))
dt2 <- data.table(varA = ymd(varB), varB = ymd(varB), varC =  varC)
setkey(dt1, varA)
setkey(dt2, varA)

dt2[dt1,, roll = T]
```

Answer (score 1):

`findInterval` in base R may be helpful here. For example,

Coerce VarA and VarB to Date objects and use `findInterval` to create a new column with the rows in df2 (i.e., VarB indices) that match the conditions you specified for each VarA.

```
df1$row_match <- findInterval(as.Date(df1$varA), as.Date(df2$varB))
```

Then create new corresponding column (rows in df2) to join/merge on

```
df2$row_match <- seq_len(nrow(df2))

df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "row_match")
#> df3
#  row_match       varA       varB   varC
#1         1 2018-01-03 2018-01-02 201801
#2         2 2018-01-06 2018-01-05 201802
#3         3 2018-01-15 2018-01-13 201804
#4         4 2018-01-25 2018-01-21 201809
```

Comment: Thanks for this, when i run this on my whole data set I get the error: Error in findInterval(as.Date(df1$VarA), as.Date(df2$VarB)) : 
  'vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly and not contain NAs.

I tried to sort the column so the dates would increase but still the same error?

Comment: are there any NAs in the date column? you might have to coerce date columns in a new object as an intermediate step to check for NAs.

Comment: I've just revisited this, and I have no NAs in the date column, not sure why this error is still happening

Answer (score -1):

you can try

```
library(tidyverse)
map(df1$varA, function(x)  df2[between(df2$varB, x, x),]) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  bind_cols(df1,.)
        varA       varB   varC
1 2018-01-03 2018-01-02 201801
2 2018-01-25 2018-01-21 201809
3 2018-01-15 2018-01-13 201804
4 2018-01-06 2018-01-05 201802
```

The idea is to find intervals using tidyverse function `map` & `between`, then add `df1`.